# I cant figure out a way to make my code loop

Tags: c++

I am complete starter and i cant figure out how to use the while function in a very simple calucator code.

ive already tried putting the while function in the code in different ways but nothing of it seems to work it just stop without even giving me the final result of the first "problem"

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number1;
    int number2;
    char op;
    int result;

    cout << "Give first number: ";
    cin >> number1;

    cout << "Give second number: ";
    cin >> number2;

    cout << "Chose operator(+ - / * ): ";
    cin >> op;

    if (op == '+')
    {
        result = number1 + number2;
    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        result = number1 - number2;
    }
    else if (op == '*')
    {
        result = number1 * number2;
    }
    else if (op == '/')
    {
        result = number1 / number2;
    }

cout << "The result is: " << result << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

everything its working fine this way i just want it to loop after the first problem and ask again for another one...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you include the code you tried with `while` loop?

Comment: [c++ flow control](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+flow+control)

Answer (score 2):

> I am complete starter and i cant figure out how to use the while function in a very simple calucator code.

Its time for you to get your hands on a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)...

**Syntax of `while` loop:** `while (some_condition) { /* Body... */ }`

**Rectified code of above problem:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number1, number2, result;
    char op;
    bool is_loop = true;

    while (is_loop) {
        std::cout << "Give first number: ";
        std::cin >> number1;

        std::cout << "Give second number: ";
        std::cin >> number2;

        std::cout << "Chose operator(+ - / * ): ";
        std::cin >> op;

        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            result = number1 + number2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = number1 - number2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = number1 * number2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = number1 / number2;
            break;
        default:
            is_loop = false;
        }
        std::cout << "The result is: " << result << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for some reason i needed to add #include "pch.h" also it tells me that cout and cin arent  members of std?

Comment: ohh it worked when i pasted in an empty project maybe the Solusion was the problem Thanks btw

Comment: @raphaell *PCH* stands for *Pre-compiled header*, which, in fact, is a **pre-compile** header for your program where you are *required* to include the necessary headers you need to keep the main code *as clean and as relevant as possible*... Judging by this fact, I can see that you are using an MSVC compiler, whose default precompiled-header is `stdafx.h` which can be [changed/disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2017)...

Comment: 1 more thing i tried to change the default: is_loop = flase; break; to case: 'q': is_loop = flase; break; to quit but it doesnt work why is that?   although it worked the first time the second didnt

Comment: @raphaell It is working as intended for me, did you mean `case 'q': case 'Q': is_loop = false;` because the ASCII characters are case-sensitive...

Comment: yes it worked for me as well but only 1 time when i run it again i get an error

Comment: i found a way to make it work every time without crashing i just puted case 'q' : result = is_loop = flase

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this.. this might be the simplest way of doing this..

```
do{
//your calculator code
char ch;
cout<<"Do you want to continue"<<endl;
cin>>ch;
while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');
```